# Find workbook by beginning of its name

Tags: vba, excel

I have some problem on getting a message box

```
Sub FindingNewWBNAme()

    For Each Wb In Application.Workbooks ' I'm activating all open workbooks
        If Left(Wb.Name, 6) = "CA-DIS" Then ' i want to find particular workbook
            MsgBox "Found"   'Incase find i need found message box
        End If

        If Left(Wb.Name, 6) <> "CA-DIS" Then  'Incase not find i need not found
            MsgBox "Not Found"
        End If

    Next

End Sub
```

---

Also I require the workbook to be sleeted with particular name
like WBK 1 or WBK2 ... etc..

I'm trying

```
Dim WB as workbook
Dim WBK1 as workbook
Set WBK1 = "CA-DIS" '----> i have found this name using first 6 letters
```

Comment: `if statement` is case sensitive, so `CA-DIS` not equals `ca-dis`, did you know about that?

Comment: use one `if/then/else` instead of two separate mutually exclusive `if` statements

Comment: answering the second part what you need is probably this line of code: `set wbk1 = wb`.

Comment: Just a Note: "*I have some problem on getting a message box*" Is not a useful error description. You should always include at least what is going wrong, what did you expect instead and where you got stuck or errors (and which). Otherwise we have to guess what your issue is.

Comment: Thank you each and everyone who replied to my concern and im really sorry if my words are wrong.. but i still have confuse on set wbk1 = wb but it is not choosing CA-DIS file which i found  i want this to name , i'd request some one to help me out how to activate only "CA-DIS" file while multiple wrkbooks in open

Comment: what are you thinking? ... you will get a popup message for every single worksheet in the workbook. ... what are you going to do if you have 50 worksheets? you will have to close each of those 50 message boxes.

Comment: @jsotola I think this is just a intermediate code or [mcve] to illustrate the issue and will probably replaced by its actual code later.

Comment: what does `sleeted` mean?

Comment: Sir/Madam,   i have a file name called "CA-disbursal-DETAILS-281120171156" in this "CA-disbursal-DETAILS-" is a standard word but numeric keeps on change each time i download from the server , so what i want is i want find this workbook using first 6 letters and also i want this work book name is something like wbk1 wbk2 etc.. bcz i do have to match data with multiple workbooks also i have already named them as x wb , y wb etc...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Untested**

Is this what you are trying?

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim WBK1 As Workbook

    For Each wb In Application.Workbooks
        If UCase(Left(Trim(wb.Name), 6)) = "CA-DIS" Then
            Set WBK1 = wb
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    If Not WBK1 Is Nothing Then
        With WBK1
            '~~> Do what you want
        End With
    Else
        MsgBox "Workbook CA-DIS not found"
    End If
End Sub
```

**Explanation**

1. `Trim(wb.Name)` trims leading and trailing spaces.
2. `Left(Trim(wb.Name), 6)` will give the 6 chars that you are looking for
3. `UCase(Left(Trim(wb.Name), 6))` will convert it to Uppercase.

Comment: Thank you very much Siddharth Rout sir Also for each and everyone who answered me , I'm expecting everyone's continued support endeavor....

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub GetWorkbookByHeader()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim wbDis As Workbook

    For Each wb In Application.Workbooks
        If UCase(wb.Name) Like "CA-DIS*" Then
        'OR:' If UCase(Left(Trim(wb.Name), 6)) = "CA-DIS" Then
            Set wbDis = wb
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    ' Exit if no matching workbook was found.
    If wbDis Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "No Disb workbook!"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'We have a matching workbook (stored in wbDis), continue:

    ... ' ===>>> You were getting an error because wbDis was "nothing" and therefore did not have a worksheets(1) property.

End Sub
```

Adding to Siddharth Rout's Answer:
You can also use the "like" operator (it is more flexible and more easy to change and tailor to your specific needs):

```
UCase(wb.Name)) like "CA-DIS*"
```

`*` is a wildcard you can use to match any string of characters.

You can also use other wildcards like:

`?` - to match a single character (you can repeat it to match a specific number of characters)

`[0-9]` - to match only numbers (you can restrict the number range further, for instance to match ony numbers from 1 to 3 `[1-3]`)

`[A-z]` - to match only letters (again you can restrict the range, for instance `A-Z`for upper case only or `[a-z]` for lowercase only).

And there are endless combinations for you to match specific paterns like:

`[a-cA-C]` - to match a character in the set {A,B,C,a,b,c}

`[0-5a-cA-C]` - to match a character in the set {1,2,3,4,5,A,B,C,a,b,c}

And you can deny the pattern within the brackets:
`[!a]` - Match anything other than 'a'

Don't forget that if you need to match an asterisk (`*`) or other "special" characters you need to enclose them in brackets:
`[*]` - Literally matches an asterisk

This really is a powerful tool (and if you ever need more power than this, you can check out Regular Expressions, which can be used in visual basic if you add the appropriate reference).

More info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/like-operator

Comment: Sub CopyByHeader()
    Dim wb1 As Workbook
    Dim Disb As Workbook
    For Each wb In Application.Workbooks
        If UCase(Left(Trim(wb.Name), 6)) = "CA-DIS" Then
                Set Disb = wb1
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
        
' "CA-DIS" WB1 name set as Disb
    Dim CurrentWS As Worksheet
    Set CurrentWS = ActiveSheet

    Dim SourceWS As Worksheet
    Set SourceWS = Disb.Worksheets(1) ===>>> here im getting error
    Dim SourceHeaderRow As Integer: SourceHeaderRow = 1
    Dim SourceCell As Range

Comment: After the "for each" loop you should check if the Disb variable is "nothing" (in other words if it "contains" a workbook): just put this after the "for each" loop `If Disb Is Nothing Then Exit Sub`